# Употребление слова «малой»

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Правильно ли употреблять слово *малой* в отношении одежды, её размера?
Например: **плащ стал малой**.
Или допустимо говорить только «мал» (*плащ стал мал*)?

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить его галочкой.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: **плащ стал мал**.

Прилагательное ***малый*** многозначное и имеет полную и краткую форму, но в приведенном примере возможна **только краткая форма.**

**МАЛЫЙ,** 1. (обычно кратк.; полн. - при сопоставлении однородных предметов, явления и т.п.). Незначительный по величине, размеру, росту, длине и т.п. (противоп.: большой; для краткой формы - велик). Мал ростом.  2. Незначительный по силе, степени проявления.  М-ая сила ветра.  3. Не имеющий существенного значения.  М. успех. 5. Разг. Небольшой по возрасту; малолетний. М-ые дети.  6. **только кратк.: мал, мала, мало. (противоп.: велик). Куртка мала. Пальто мало. Ботинки малы.**

Примечание. Слово ***малОй*** не относится к нормативной лексике, пример употребления: Ты, малой, откуда? [http://teenslang.su/content/Малой](http://teenslang.su/content/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Answer (score 1):

***Плащ стал (каков?) мал*** - требует именно такой формы, все варианты с "малый", "мал**о**й", "малым" - или неупотребительны, или неправильны стилистически.

Слово "мал**о**й" имеет только одно значение, разговорное: маленький, меньший (ребенок, брат) и используется только как существительное. Полная форма прилагательного "мал" - только "малый".

При этом в форме "стал кем-то/чем-то" требуется творительный падеж.
Грамматически форма *"плащ стал малым"* возможна, хотя она очень неестественна. Даже в том фантастическом случае, если кому-то потребуется сказать, что плащ стал ребенком, то *"плащ стал малым"*. Хотя в искусственном контексте что-то подобное возможно.

*Было у меня три плаща: большой, средний и малый. Малый я выбросил, и средний плащ стал малый/малым*.

Но в абсолютном большинстве случаев такие фразы считаются предикативными и требуют краткой формы.

Сравните.
*Плащ стал красив/красивым*. Вариант "красивый" крайне редок в современном языке.

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь понято)